# jQuery Scroll 100% (Animated)

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I've been trying to figure out how to make jQuery scroll down by 100% in some fancy animated way when someone clicks the down button.

I wanted to have an up and down button instead of a conventional navigation bar. I have four panels of 100% height and width, and wanted the fixed-position up and down buttons to move to the next panel.

I figured I'd do this by incrementing the movement by 100% (down) and -100% (up), but I'm not sure how I'd make jQuery do this. I've tried several different methods all to no avail. I'd like the simplest method possible to achieve this.

P.S. I'd like to scroll vertically. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a really nice plugin which gives you a lot of choices how you want to scroll and its really simple and fun to use.
http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

Answer (score 1):

SEE THIS TO SCROLL DOWN 100%

JQUERY

```
$('body').animate({
scrollTop:$(document).height()
});
```

Comment: maybe $('html, body') is better than $('body')

Answer (score 1):

If you are going with JQuery and don't want to become a plugin author yourself, there are plenty of free plugins out there to scroll through items.

Try the scroller examples in jquerytools http://jquerytools.org/

It supports the next/prev buttons you want and vertical scrolling http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/vertical.html

Answer (score 0):

A go-top button is as simple as this (with any style you want):

```
<a id="goTop">Top</a>

$("#goTop").click(function() {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 400);
});
```

If you want to navigate to different points, simply put anchors ('a' tag) in these points. Then you can move with jQuery setting the position value to the 'scrollTop' above. Or you can use just html (without the scroll animation) with the 'name' and 'href' attributes:

```
<a name="top"></a>
<!-- Content -->
<a name="bottom"></a>

<a href="#top">Go top</a>
<a href="#bottom">Go bottom</a>
```

Comment: I put the go-top as an example, since the code is the same. As I commented, one way to do what you want is to put an anchor at every panel and use them as reference to navigate. You will need to apply some logic to get which is the next/previous panel, but that is up to your code.